# Is my question in the wrong place?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

[How much degenerate matter is there, compared to other states of matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/415750/)  hasn't had any replies. I'm thinking about starting a bounty on it, but maybe it would be more appropriate in Chemistry or Astronomy SE instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a great question, but I think it is technically on topic here. So no, I would say it's not in the wrong place.

You're welcome to put a bounty on it to get it more attention, or you're welcome to delete it yourself and repost it on another SE site. (Bear in mind that you won't be able to do this if the question gets any upvoted answers.)